# Angular ng-hide or ng-show ? why?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I have seen this questions many times, but not once have I seen a normal answer.

What is the difference between ng-hide and ng-show? is there one? if so when to use one or the other ( I understand ng-if, I am asking only about this two).

I hope some one knows
thanks.

Comment: You can use either of them to get the desired result. However both  `ng-hide` and `ng-show` exists for sementics.

Comment: do you want to know if them are used for particular cases? If that's so I only could think of usage like this: `<div id="hidden" ng-hide>Hidden</div>` compared to this  `<div id="show_only_if" ng-show="condition === true">COnditionned<div> `

Comment: so  `ng-hide ` can be used without a condition as a replacement for  `display: none `

Comment: If you would ask what is the difference between `ng-show` and `ng-if`, it's more reasonable. This case is very clear.

Comment: @vahidnajafi the difference between ng-if is well written and understood in angular site.
that's why I ask on this two.

Comment: @sTx you are saying ng-hide can be use with condition while ng-show take a bool ?

Comment: It's more like, like this is more logic, but both can be used without a condition; but If you want to hide something and not use css you use  `ng-hide ` - on the other hand there is no reason to have an element with  `display; none ` in css and then show it with  `ng-show' on page load

Comment: and @vahidnajafi, if it would be so clear I guess you could have just written the answer.

Comment: thanks for you help @sTx

Comment: no need to -  idea is that you use them depending on your needs and the situation you are facing

Comment: @user24136 Your question down voted a while ago. I up voted you, because it's every one's right to ask  a question. But in this question, the answer is just knowing about the difference between 0 and 1. 
Any way, Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know angularjs is a two way databinding. ng-hide and ng-show is we used for two different purpose one for hide and another for show. for example if you use one method that returns true or false. In any case hide of one element you want to show other then you need to use only one method for both hide and show.

Answer (score 3):

> The [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.
>
> The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element. The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag).

[ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) is just syntaxic sugar when you need to invert the result of the expression.

Basically, it would be the same to use `ng-show="!testSomething()"` and `ng-hide="testSomething()"`.

Answer (score 3):

All these `directive`s like `ng-hide` , `ng-show` and `ng-if` take a condition in the form of a `boolean` and show/hide from view according to `true` and `false`. The logic they use to hide and show the view are different.

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` use internally CSS like this:

```
display: none; // according to show or hide
```

But when we use ng-if- 
if condition is `true`: adds the element into DOM.
if condition is `false`: removes element from the DOM.

It means `ng-show` keeps the elements in the DOM and the cost of watcher remain the same, while the user isn't allowed to see the element in the DOM. 
And if you replace `ng-show` with an ng-if, you might witness considerable improvements in the DOM because those extra watches are not there to take responsibility.

If a particular element has `ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide` in the DOM, then it can have a performance impact.
When you use `ng-if`, the app will be faster compared to ng-show/ng-hide. But the difference is not noticeable. But if you are using these directives in animations, then there is a possibility of performance issues.

**In short, if you can remove an element from DOM, then you should use ng-if, otherwise you should use ng-show or ng-hide.**

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that's why I ask spacifaclly about hide and show and not about ng-if.

Comment: why the comments have 5 min time to edit !!!?????

what I meant to say that the first part you wrote was more relevant to the question then the conclusion.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-show
```

Lets you make the display:block of the element when expression is true while `ng-hide` lets you set the `display:none` when the expression is true. They are just opposite to each other. Don't get confused. Use only one, `ng-show` as `ng-show="exp"` and `ng-show="!exp"` to show or hide an element